# Preserve trailing whitespace Sybase

Tags: sybase, whitespace

I have a big chunk of textual data which I split and write multiple rows of a `varchar(255)` column of a table. Sometimes, the last character happens to be a space. When I read back this row, the trailing space is chopped and I get only 254 characters. This messes up my data when I append the next row to the end of this one.

1. My code sends the full 255 char (incl space) to the DB API. How can I check that the trailing space is actually written to the table?
2. I am not in a position to rewrite/redesign legacy code. Is there any setting - either in the DB, DB interface, read/write calls etc - that I can use to preserve the trailing space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is designed behaviour varchars will strip. If you want to keep all the filling spaces you have to use char columns. So the only thing you can do is change the schems

Comment: Thanks Mark. Verified that changing the schema preserves the trailing space. If you don't mind, I'll wait a day for any alternative solutions before I tick your answer.

Comment: I tried it on Sybase 15.5 and even with a char column, it strips out the trailing spaces when I insert.

Comment: @javid Jamae this should be a separate question including how you are inserting

Comment: @Mark - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6553229/does-sybase-support-string-types-that-it-doesnt-right-trim

Comment: Same thing in `ASE 15.7`, `VARCHAR` or `CHAR` regardless, trailing spaces are stripped. This is a crime against humanity.