# Does Sybase support string types that it doesn't right trim?

Tags: sybase

The accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943277/preserve-trailing-whitespace-sybase/2943357) claims that using a char column will preserve ***all*** filling spaces in a string in Sybase, but that is not the behavior I am seeing (unless I'm mistaken about what 'filling spaces' means). For example, when I run the following script:

```
create table #check_strings
(
    value char(20) null
)

insert into #check_strings values (null)
insert into #check_strings values ('')
insert into #check_strings values (' ')
insert into #check_strings values ('     ')
insert into #check_strings values ('blah')
insert into #check_strings values ('blah ')
insert into #check_strings values ('blah    ')
insert into #check_strings values ('    blah    ')

select value, len(value) from #check_strings
```

I get the following output:

```
[NULL]            - [NULL]
[single space]    - 1
[single space]    - 1
[single space]    - 1
blah              - 4
blah              - 4
blah              - 4
[four spaces]blah - 8
```

Is there any way to get Sybase to *not* strip off trailing spaces? Additionally, is there any way to get it to save an empty string as an empty string, and not as a single space?

I'm using Sybase 15.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.sqlug/html/sqlug/sqlug208.htm

"When you create a char, unichar, or nchar column that allows nulls, Adaptive Server converts it to a varchar, univarchar, or nvarchar column and uses the storage rules for those datatypes."

Please, check not null column.

Comment: Thanks. It works with the not null setting, but the problem is that it always returns strings of length 20 (e.g. I insert a blank string, and it returns 20 spaces on the select). This is not an acceptable solution. Varchar is the way to go, but this behavior of modifying the data that I'm inserting is quite an annoying behavior in Sybase.

Comment: Some time ago I had to always add one character at the end in the same case. Of course I had to remove this last character at the client side. This is't best but working in my case soution.

Answer (score 2):

To have fixed length on char columns, you must use the `not null` attribute.

For variable length columns, use varchar or char with a `null` attribute.

Then to measure the real data size use the `datalength` function not the `len` function nor the `charlength` function.